# $U = (I-iT) (I + iT) ^ {-1}$ is a unitary operator when T is self-adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ complex inner product space of finite dimension and $T$ an operator over $V$. Show that the transformation
$$U = (I-iT) (I + iT) ^ {-1}$$
is a unitary operator

My Attempt:

$$\langle U \alpha, U\alpha \rangle = \langle (I−iT)(I+iT)^{-1} \alpha , (I−iT)(I+iT)^{-1} \alpha \rangle = 
\langle \alpha , (I−iT)^{-1}(I+iT)(I−iT)(I+iT)^{-1} \alpha \rangle $$

and I need proof this  $(I−iT)^{-1}(I+iT)(I−iT)(I+iT)^{-1} = I $

Comment: This is straight from the definition of a unitary operator. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EuYu           This <Ux,Ux>=<$(I-ix)(I+iX)^{-1}$ x , $(I-ix)(I+iX)^{-1}1$ x > = < x , $(I-ix)^{-1}(I+iX)(I-ix)(I+iX)^{-1}$ x >

and I need proof this  $(I-ix)^{-1}(I+iX)(I-ix)(I+iX)^{-1}$ = I

Comment: Let $T = -iI$. Then $iT = I$, and $U$ will be zero.

Comment: @user63192 Can you please add your attempt to the question instead of as a comment? Also, you're using $x$ as both a vector and as the operator.

Comment: @EuYu          Yes I'm sorry :D

Comment: You have $< Ax, y > =< x, Ay >$ in your post. This only holds for $A$ self-adjoint. Did you forget to add something in your post?

Comment: No I have $<Ax,y> = <x, A^{-1} y> $

Comment: It should be assumed that $T$ is a self-adjoint operator. With this qassumption, 40votes has given a proof.  Without this assumption, the result is not generally true.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the operator-valued version of the fact that the map
$$x\mapsto \frac{1-ix}{1+ix}$$
transforms the real line onto the unit circle.

In operator terms, the real line becomes the set of *self-adjoint operators*. And the unit circle is the group of *unitary operators*.

So, let  $T$ be self-adjoint. Then $(I\pm iT)^*=(I\mp iT)$, which implies $U^*=(I-iT)^{-1}(I+iT)$. Since all operators of the form $aI+bT$ commute with each other, we have
$$U^*U = (I-iT)^{-1}(I+iT) (I-iT)(I+iT)^{-1} =(I-iT)^{-1}(I-iT)(I+iT) (I+iT)^{-1} =I $$
and 
$$UU^* =  (I-iT)(I+iT)^{-1} (I-iT)^{-1}(I+iT) = (I-iT) (I-iT)^{-1}(I+iT)^{-1}(I+iT) =I $$